# Get Current Constraint of Element

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am using **NSLayoutConstraint** class and creating the outlet to to a element to modify it's constraint in code later onwards.

Outlet Declaration:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var forgotPasswordBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Modification of Constraint in code:

```
self.forgotPasswordBottomConstraint.constant += changeInforgotPasswordBottomConstraint
```

Now I want to get the initial constraint of the element when the view loads. (ie: Before I am modifying the constraint in code)

Answer (score 0):

You can access your constraint on an element by looping through it like

```
for item in self.forgotPassword.constraints {
       ....
```